# Creating a dynamic width items for carousel slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently in the middle making my carousel responsive. So far I've managed to make it responsive only if the user resizes and refreshes browser only then it will resize programmatically. How can I make it resize without having to refresh the browser.

**Update:**

I tried working with the answers below. Currently it stays on a fixed value even if I resize browser. Inside my css there is no fixed value placed

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sliderWidth = 0;
  var sliderContainer = $('.slider-container');
  var slider = $('.slider-container .slider');
  var sliderItems = $('.slider li');
  var sliderContainerWidth = sliderContainer.width();

  sliderItems.width(sliderContainerWidth / 2);

  $('.slider-container ul.slider').children().each(function() {
    sliderWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
    slider.width(sliderWidth + 1000);
  });

  $('.btns .prev').on('click', function() {
    prevSlide();
  })

  function prevSlide() {
    var sliderItemsWidth = sliderItems.width();
    var leftIndent = parseInt($(sliderItems).css('left')) - sliderItemsWidth;

    function animate() {
      $('.slider-container .slider:not(:animated)').animate({
        'left': leftIndent
      }, 100)
    }
    animate();
  }
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.wrapper .slider-container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
}

.wrapper .slider-container .slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .slider-container .slider li {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider-container">
    <ul class="slider">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="btns">
      <li class="prev">prev</li>
      <li class="next">next</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add a snippet of your code

Comment: Make your slider initialisation into a function and call it on window resize? although you wouldn't need to rebind events

Comment: @Pete Sorry for my ignorance, but how do I implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments, you can put the resizing bits into a function and call that on window resize:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sliderContainer = $('.slider-container');
  var slider = $('.slider-container .slider');
  var sliderItems = $('.slider li');
  
  function resize() {
      var sliderWidth = 0;
      var sliderContainerWidth = sliderContainer.width();
    
      sliderItems.width(sliderContainerWidth / 2);

      $('.slider-container ul.slider').children().each(function() {
        sliderWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
        slider.width(sliderWidth + 1000);
      });
  }
  

  $('.btns .prev').on('click', function() {
    prevSlide();
  })

  function prevSlide() {
    var sliderItemsWidth = sliderItems.width();
    var leftIndent = parseInt($(sliderItems).css('left')) - sliderItemsWidth;

    function animate() {
      $('.slider-container .slider:not(:animated)').animate({
        'left': leftIndent
      }, 100)
    }
    animate();
  }
  
  resize();  // call onload
  
  $(window).on('resize', function () {
      resize();  // call when browser is resized
  });
})
```

Comment: Aside from the error  `$(winow).on('resize', function ()` in this line. The items inside the carousel doesn't seem to be resizing dynamically at all

Comment: @clestcruz this is just showing how to implement it - given the code you have provided.  If this doesn't work, then you need to figure out what resizes it in the first place and place that into the window resize function

Comment: If you are talking about `$(window).on('resize'` no firing, try changing it to `$(window).resize`

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the `sliderWidth` var also needs moving into the resize function (so it is reset to 0 when the function is called)